# how to evaluate a vaiable's type without really execute it?

Tags: php, autocomplete

I am trying to write an auto-complete tools like jedi (a python autocompletion tool).
My question is how to get the type of $var without really execute the code?

```
   <?php
       class A
       {
       }
       class B 
       {
       }

       class C
       {
       }

       function a ($p, $q) {
           if ($p == 10) {
               return  new A();
            }
           if ($p > $q) {
               return  new B();
            }
            return  new C();
        }
        $var =  a(10, 8);
        print_r($var);
```

The reason why I don't want to really execute the code is that maybe the code is really dangerous(etc. delete some data from database).

Any suggetion about this question or how to write a php version jedi is welcome.

Comment: [get_class](http://php.net/get_class)?

Comment: You could use the datatype in the function? rather than just saying `function ...($a`) you can use `function ...(string $a)` or `function ...(array $a)` plus user inputted code isn't executed unless outputted or evaled... Also your code is sloppy, use a switch statement

Comment: @JonStirling I don't think it will work, I know this method, but what I want to get is the value of  parameter passed to get_class($var).

Comment: @kevin .... what? What result are you wanting if we go by your example?

Comment: Adding auto completion to arbitrary code (especially a dynamically typed language) is likely to be very complex. You may want to look into the tokenizer in PHP which allows parsing PHP code: http://php.net/manual/en/book.tokenizer.php

Comment: @KyleThomas Yes, I could, but it depeends on the code, I cannot reply on it. Many codes  lookes like my example.

Comment: @Jim Yes, it's very complex. Thanks for you suggestion and I will go to get a further look at the tokenizer.